# '.all?' method's strange behaviour

Tags: ruby

I am unable to understand what `all?` does. In the following code, the first two lines are the same. Why are the outputs different? Is it a bug or is it its default behaviour?

```
[false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true].all? # => false
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true].all? # => true
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1].all? # => true
```

Comment: I guess you mean lines 19 and 21 are the same, in which case you mistakenly assume `0 == false`.That's not the case in ruby.

Comment: @sawa please keep the lines numbers,otherwise my answers are invalid in some directions.

Comment: because everything except `false` and `nil` evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Enumerable#all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) says :

> If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj| obj } which will cause all? to return true when none of the collection members are false or nil.

In your second line,the code return `true` as **none of the collection members are `false` or `nil`**

In your third line code returns `true` ,as all objects in your code collection (0,1) are `true`,as in Ruby all objects are `true` except `nil` and `false`.

In your first line,the code return `false`,as the collection contains `false` values along with `true` values.

Comment: Thanks it helps.. It returns `false` if there is a `false` or `nil`. But I want `true` if there is `false` and `false` only when there is `nil`. Is there any method?

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman `ary.any?(&:nil?)` should work in that case, it returns `true` is there's a `nil` value and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman Use `a = [true,false] ;
a.all?{|e| !e.nil?}
# => true` and `a = [true,false,nil] ;
a.all?(&:nil?)
# => false`

Comment: Just a simple `a.include?(nil)` returns true if there is a nil in your array.

Comment: @Meier sure sure.. I was stuck in `any?` and `all?` ... :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a ruby method, which is defined as follows:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj| obj } which will cause all? to return true when none of the collection members are false or nil.

See the documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).